# Sequence of tests in UIAutomation

Tags: ios-ui-automation

I want to play several tests one by one, in the same project of course. Each scenario starts where the previous has stopped. Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use this https://github.com/douban/ynm3k

and use testcase to manage the test one by one

and in jenkins execute shell:

`sh setup.sh sh runTests.sh ./sample/alltests.js "/Users/komejun/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/1622F505-8C07-47E0-B0F0-3A125A88B329/Recipes.app/"`

and the report will be automatically created in ./ynmsk-report/test.xml

Answer (score 0):

I created a script that imported each test case one by one in order. They all run, one after another and show pass/fail for each. In a new script just write #import "testscriptname.js";
Do that for each test you want to run from start to finish.